# Division between rows of a matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

I'm having some problems performing a division between rows of a matrix in Matlab; i.e. dividing two subsequent rows elementwise. 
E.g., I need to write a function that transforms the following matrix `A` into the matrix `B`:

`A = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6; 7, 8, 9]`

`B = [4, 2.5, 2; 1.75, 1.6, 1.5]`

How can I do this?

Edit: Obviously the above is just a toy example, I need to find a solution that can be extended easily to higher order matrices.

Comment: Could you also add an example with a "higher order matrix" you want the answer for?

Comment: The code should work even for a matrix of dimension, let's say, `5042x89`; that's why I asked for a function that can generalize the process!

Comment: To me it seems that the solution posted below will work even in that case.

Comment: Ok, I will try to adapt the code!

Comment: @james42 You don't have to adapt anything. The code will work as is. I just tested it on a 5042x89 matrix and it works in less than 0.01 seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I was getting stuck because I wanted to write the function with a for cycle -_-'

Comment: @james42 You gotta kill those cycles! Fly on vectorized jets!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
>> B = A(2:end, :) ./ A(1:end-1, :)
B = 
    [ 4.0    2.5   2
      1.75   1.6   1.5 ]
```

Comment: Yep, I know... But I need to deal with bigger matrices, and that's why I'm looking for a function that does this job!

Comment: @james42 This does work for arbitrary sized matrices. Or what do you think will not work?

Comment: @james42 Did you try this code on an arbitrarily-sized 2d matrix?

Comment: Yes, it works! I was getting lost using a for cycle! Thanks Chris!